# Solve a shell script where i have to delete the files with size 0?

Tags: linux

I have to delete with permission the files with size 0 created by a user from a certain path. The user and the path are positional parameters.
i thought of making a "for" where i go through the files from a certain user and then with "find" to remove the ones empty from the wanted path.
Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /$1/*

do

find /$2 -size -0b -type 'f' -exec rm -i {} \;

done
```

But it's not working, can you tell me why?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do: what is `$1`? Did you make sure to provide both parameters to the script? Also, there is a `-0b` is the minus a typo here or in the real script too?

Comment: $1 is the positional parameter for the user and $2 for the pathway and for -0b i found on a site that this is how you can ask if the size is 0 bytes.

Comment: If $1 is the user do you expect to get when you run 'for file in /$1/*; do echo $file; done'? What do you get? I would start from that.
Please also expand on what exactly you need $1 and $2 to be. It could really help you get an answer. 
And as a side note, file is a common shell command, I recommend replacing it as a variable with FILE or something else that would be less confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(recommend editing the posting where the script is complete and presented as code; eg the leading # is missing; note: invert the script and click the {} button)

As shown, the script seems somewhat odd; recommend checking stuff like whether the cmd-line arg-count is correct and then whether args `$1` and `$2` are valid; the expression `/$1/*` indicates you want to repeat the same search based on the wildcard `*` result of everything within the absolute path `/$1`, but the trailing `/*` is not needed (`find` will normally descend into subdirs), meanwhile the directory passed to `find` is the invariant abs path `/$2`.  Here's a revision with some elements guessed:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 2 ] && { echo Usage: ${0##*/} dir user 1>&2; exit 1; }

# search the unmodified dir $1 for any file owned by $2 with size 0 and run an interactive delete
find $1 -user $2 -type f -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```